# Curses keypad(True) does not get special keys

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, linux-mint, python-curses

I am trying to write code for both Python 2 and 3.  Here is my complete code that I am using to learn curses:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function

import curses
import sys
import traceback


class Cursor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(True)

    def end_window(self):
        curses.nocbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(False)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()

    def start_win(self, begin_x=0, begin_y=1, height=24, width=71):
        return curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)


def applic():
    print("yo man")
    x = Cursor()
    window = x.start_win()
    try:
        # This raises ZeroDivisionError when i == 10.
        for i in range(0, 11):
            v = i - 10
            key = window.getch()
            # EDIT - Added this debug line to verify what key gets
            window.addstr('type of {} is {}\n'.format(key, type(key)))
            if key == curses.KEY_UP:
                return
            window.addstr('10 divided by {} is {}\n'.format(v, 10 // v))
            window.refresh()

    except Exception:
        x.end_window()
        errorstring = sys.exc_info()[2]
        traceback.print_tb(errorstring)

applic()
```

My problem is that `key` will never equal `curses.KEY_UP` because getch() (or getkey()) is returning single character strings, not the entire escape key code that equals KEY_UP (`\x1b]A`).  So each time I press the up arrow in the routine, the program cycles through the three parts of the key code `\x1b`, `[`, `A`, and producing three lines of output:

```
10 divided by -10 is -1
10 divided by -9 is -2
10 divided by -8 is -2
```

for this test, I want the UP arrow key to allow me to break out before the expected exception that will occur when i equals 10.

According to the python documentation for Curses, `stdscr.keypad(True)` is supposed to allow returning the entire key code, but does not appear to do so.

Added some debugging printout information to show what is coming back.  Whether I use getch() or getkey(), the result is the same; it returns a string (the documentation indicated that an integer would be returned for getch):

```
type of ^[ is <class 'str'>
10 divided by -9 is -2
type of [ is <class 'str'>
10 divided by -8 is -2
type of A is <class 'str'>
10 divided by -7 is -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set the `keypad` property on the main window, but are reading from a different window using `getch`.  This change would make your program accept a `KEY_UP`:

```
--- curses-vs-keypad.py 2017/04/02 11:07:41     1.1
+++ curses-vs-keypad.py 2017/04/03 00:57:16
@@ -28,6 +28,7 @@
     print("yo man")
     x = Cursor()
     window = x.start_win()
+    window.keypad(True)
     try:
         # This raises ZeroDivisionError when i == 10.
         for i in range(0, 11):
```